# Oracle: How to call a PL/SQL procedure having 10 IN attributes and 2 OUT attributes?

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

Calling procedure first time, I have procedure name like below:

```
PROCEDURE add_cine(
P_User_Name In Varchar2,
p_c_number IN VARCHAR2, 
P_C_Name In Varchar2,
P_C_Id In Varchar2, 
P_Ot In Varchar2, 
P_It In Varchar2, 
p_se IN DATE,
P_Ee In Date,
p_pr IN VARCHAR2,
p_tr IN VARCHAR2,
x_eec OUT NOCOPY VARCHAR2, 
x_et OUT NOCOPY VARCHAR2
);
```

I am using oracleclient to call this procedure

When I call it like:

```
SQL> exec ADD_cine('xxsihh', '197200_90.27014-156154', '1214','197200_127014-156154', '1', '197200: IPS 1 Term 12mth GB', null, null, '197200', '90.1')
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 216:
PLS-00363: expression '197200' cannot be used as an assignment target
```

10 Parameters having IN and two having OUT but while calling i am putting IN only.

I tried other things but getting same. Any idea if I am not passing parameters correctly?

Through java code I always get:

```
PLS-00201: identifier 'ADD_CINE' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

I also tried

```
DECLARE 
errcode VARCHAR2; 
errmessage VARCHAR2; 
BEGIN 
    ADD_cine('xxsihh', '197200_90.27014-156154', '1214','197200_127014-156154', '1', '197200: IPS 1 Term 12mth GB', null, null, '197200', '90.1',errcode,errcode)
END;
```

but it is not picking by oracle client. It keep on expecting inputs
[image]

Comment: Your 'also tried' has `errcode,errcode`; that is, you use the same variable for both outputs.  You can't do that, the two outputs have to be different variables...  `errcode, errmessage`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to declare 2 OUT parameters and actually **use them** while calling the procedure:

```
DECLARE
   out_1  VARCHAR2 (20);
   out_2  VARCHAR2 (20);
BEGIN
   ADD_cine (p_user_name  => 'xxsihh',
             p_c_number   => '197200_90.27014-156154',
             p_c_name     => '1214',
             p_c_id       => '197200_127014-156154',
             p_ot         => '1',
             p_it         => '197200: IPS 1 Term 12mth GB',
             p_se         => NULL,
             p_ee         => NULL,
             p_pr         => '197200',
             p_tr         => '90.1',
             x_eec        => out_1,           --> this
             x_et         => out_2);          --> and this
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks for confirmation. I tried it in oracle client first but it is not executing same (attached screenshot of what behavior it is showing i.e not executing. Do you have information on same?

Comment: Those numbers you see ... after the last `END;`, type a slash `/` and then press ENTER.